# SOLR Magento Integration

Tags: magento-1.7, solr

Multiple errors are produced "SEVERE SolrCore org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field name" with a Magento 1.7/ Solr 4 integration using https://github.com/magentix/Solr/. Any SOLR experts available?

Comment: I had nothing but problems trying to use that module. A better alternative (if you're up to task) is to build your own module using the Solarium library (which is actively maintained and supports SOLR 4 and up).

Answer (score 1):

Show your schema.XML and Magentix_Solr_Model_Indexer class. Here https://github.com/kubaceg/Soli is my fork of this extension with sample schema.XML when you put it in solr everything should work :-)

Comment: Sooo my fork resolve your's problem?